# Insert a row based on another row's data SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, dynamic-programming, sql-insert

I made a schema example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6a134/1

Let's say I have a table called cart which contains customer_id's and item codes they want to buy.

I want to add Item "ZZZ" for any order currently in table cart that has item "ABC".

Is there a way to do with with a single SQL command?

The only way I know how to do this is if I wrote a stored procedure with a cursor and inserted a row for every customer id I find in the cart meeting my requirements.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

you can create a trigger that inserts the zzz item every single time an abc item is added... check this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa214456%28v=sql.80%29.aspx):

Comment: that would work, but what about existing rows in the table I want to update?

Comment: inside queries use CASE THEN as the if statement... basically search (CASE), if found (THEN)...google CASE THEN statements